# Xcode 3.2 Debug: Seeing whats in a string?

Tags: xcode

Does anyone know the display formatter that I would need to add to the summary field to display the contents of the NSString objects contained in the NSArray shown? I have already added the formatter below for NSArray so that it displays its contents...

```
"{(int)[$VAR count]} objects {(NSString *)[(NSArray *)$VAR description]}:s"
```

[image]

I would really like (0-6 marked in red) to display in "Summary" as follows:

0 = Monday

1 = Tuesday

2 = Wednesday

3 = Thursday ... etc.

gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to display monday, tuesday, wednesday, but not sure why yet:

1. I started with this code to create an array like what you describe:

   NSArray  * myArray2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"monday",@"tuesday",@"wednesday",nil];

   In debugger it didn't show the expected monday, tuesday, wednesday on each row.
2. This step is important: In debugger, I double clicked on the summary and pasted in the string you were using:

   {(int)[$VAR count]} objects {(NSString *)[(NSArray *)$VAR description]}:s

   That didn't work.
3. But immediately after, I clicked on the same summary field (it highlighted the string I just pasted), and then pressed the delete key, and then clicked return.

   Then it showed Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday on each row in array.

Answer (score 1):

I've had very little success with the Xcode data formatters.  It rarely seems to do what you'd expect.  Creating a data formatter bundle is more work but tends to be *slightly* more reliable (however, I still find that much of the time it will say that variables are out of scope when they quite clearly aren't).  The Xcode data formatter docs have a [tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/220-Viewing_Variables_and_Memory/variables_and_memory.html) on creating a bundle.

Answer (score 0):

`{(NSString *)[$VAR description]}:s` doesn't work?

Comment: Just tried it and I could not get it to work with an NSArray of NSStrings.